# What is the simplest way to validate a date in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using DateTime.ParseExact to parse a string from input. What is the simplest way to make sure the date complies to rules like max days in a month or no 0. month?

Comment: What's wrong with ParseExact?  Does it have problems which allows for invalid dates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do additional validation using...

```
DateTime.TryParse();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As BoltBait said, or **DateTime.TryParseExact()** if you know the exact format of the string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The answers for doing the DateTime.TryParse() are great if you are doing this check in your code behind, but if you are capturing this data on the UI, then I would highly reccomend validing the input as well before the postback to the code behind occurs.

```
<strong>Date:</strong>
<asp:textbox ID="txtEnterDate" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cvEnterDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEnterDate"
    ErrorMessage="Must Be Valid Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" 
    SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected void txtTo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tbTo = (TextBox)sender;
        DateTime wsToOUT;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(tbTo.Text, out wsToOUT))
        {
            //do something with valid date in tbTo
        }
        else
        {
            //show a nice error message
            tbTo.Focus();
        }
    }
```